# Implement Cookie and consent management in Sitecore Headless App

Tags: jss, xconnect, tracking, nextjs, cookies

I implemented the **Cookie and consent management functionality** ([Manage a contact's tracking consent choices (sitecore.com)](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-platform/manage-a-contact-s-tracking-consent-choices.html#give-consent)) in the **Sitecore 10.1** + **Sitecore NextJS (18.0.0)** using the *Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Consent.IConsentManager* in **JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor** to get/give/revoke consent by passing the **NULL** and enabled the **explicitConsentForTrackingIsRequired** (set to *true*):

- consentManager.GetConsent(null)
- consentManager.GiveConsent(null)
- consentManager.RevokeConsent(null)

Based on consent accepted/rejected by user:

- **Accepted:**

  - If current Tracker is null or not active, then I will start the Tracking
  - If consent is null or consent not given (consent.IsGiven) from GetConsent then , I am setting the GetConsent(null)
- **Rejected:**

  - If current Tracker is not null or active then I will end the Tracking and Visit
  - If consent is null or consent given (consent.IsGiven) from GetConsent then , I am setting the RevokeConsent(null)
  - If SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE present then expire the cookie

After upgrade to Sitecore 10.3 or Sitecore 10.2 + NextJS (20.3), I found that

- SC_TRACKING_CONSENT not being set for user (Anonymous or Known users) but in code behind its showing with Domain name as NULL
- If Anonymous user accept the consent then also SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE not being set for user but in code behind its showing with FE Domain name (.amit.com)
- In xDB Shard DB, consent for user always set as TRUE
  {"Key":"xDB.Tracker.Consent.amitsite","Value":{"**ConsentValue**":**1**,"ConsentDateTime":"2023-02-07T11:20:12.3503771Z"}}

In Sitecore 10.1 + Sitecore NextJS (18.0.0), the above issues are not present and functionality working as expected.

Has anyone implemented the cookie consent banner in Sitecore NextJS to enable/disable the tracking of users or faced the above issue after upgrade to Sitecore 10.2 or Sitecore 10.3?

Answer (score 0):

Because in your steps, you mentioned that you are using revoke too, can you check if **"SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE"** exists?

Because If tracking is in progress

it invalidates the **SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKI**E and and updates the contact's consent choice. and this choice is stored in the **SC_TRACKING_CONSENT** cookie.

So may be it is coming from there?

Because your `XDB` is showing correct values

Comment: I have enabled the Explicit Consent, so SC_TRACKING_CONSENT would be present in all the cases.